# Deciphering lines from 1909 Ellis Island record?

Tags: palaeography, immigration, new-york-city, 1900s-decade

I am trying to read some lines from an Ellis Island record.

The record is from 1909 and I managed to read everything except the details of the contact/address for the person in question.

It is the record at line 10. It should be an address in New York.

[image]

Comment: Use the indexed version of the immigrant's name to look up the entry on FamilySearch for a much-better-quality image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually says "Illinois st, Detroit", but is part of the record above. If you go back up to line four and count down two lines (contact name and address) for each entry until number ten, you will see what I mean.

The entry for line ten starts underneath, from "father", and is over two lines - the address looks like 325 ? 28th Street, New York.  The ? should probably be E or W (East or West).

Comment: Thank to @nkjt, who confirmed my reading of the address.
For what concerns the name of the contact persons, I am positive he was not the actual father. So I was thinking about 'father' in the sense of a priest.
The name probably is Bocco G. Battista.